# Correct syntax for joins

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a problem with phpmyadmin syntax. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', visitor_name, visitor_email, visitor_phone) AS visitor_info,
    session_geoip_country,  
    session_geoip_city,
    visitor_chats_count,
    agents_names, 
    chat_id,
    SUBSTRING( visitor_description, 1, 100 ) AS Manager_note
FROM
    client_jivo_chat_finished
INNER JOIN
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.timestamp, client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.message 
ON
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id = client_jivo_chat_finished.chat_id
```

and error is:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id = client_jivo_chat_finished.chat_i' at line 8"

Comment: did you check the manual as suggested by the error message details?

Comment: Checked and and understood that it has only general suggestions about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct as you are joining table column. Here is the modified version. Hope this works.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', visitor_name, visitor_email, visitor_phone) AS visitor_info,
    session_geoip_country,  
    session_geoip_city,
    visitor_chats_count,
    agents_names, 
    chat_id,
    SUBSTRING( visitor_description, 1, 100 ) AS Manager_note
FROM
    client_jivo_chat_finished
INNER JOIN
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages 
ON
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id = client_jivo_chat_finished.chat_id
```

### You shoud join two table on a column. Just remove this part.

`INNER JOIN
client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.timestamp, client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.message`

Comment: Here is slightly modified version:
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', visitor_name, visitor_email, visitor_phone) AS visitor_info,
    session_geoip_country,  
    session_geoip_city,
    visitor_chats_count,
    agents_names, 
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id,
    SUBSTRING( visitor_description, 1, 100 ) AS Manager_note
FROM
    client_jivo_chat_finished
INNER JOIN
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages 
ON
    client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id = client_jivo_chat_finished.chat_id;
Changed chat_id to client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id

Answer (score 1):

You need to comprehend first what you have tried to do. There are two table references after your `INNER JOIN` syntax, which is not allowed. Please check the [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) reference manual of how to use it.

In short, you have tried

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    tableA, tableB ON <cond>
```

If you want to join with a table, either by `INNER`, or `LEFT`, or another joins (again see the manual reference linked in the first paragraph), you have to select **one** table reference and add a condition based on that table reference. Not two or more.

In short,

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    tableA ON tableA.columnX = table1.columnFoo
INNER JOIN
    tableB ON tableB.columnY = table1.columnBar
```

is the right syntax if you want to join with two another tables. The conditional part after `ON` clause can vary.

Some people however creates a temporary table by combining it first before joining them. This is actually an exception practice and only useful if the requirements demands it (or to reduce the complexity).

In addition, you also tried to use

```
INNER JOIN client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.timestamp
```

You are trying to join with a column instead of a reference table (unless you have named a table this way which is bad practice). This is visible by the `.` in the name, which is like

```
 A.Foo = "Check for column named as 'Foo' in table A"
```

Try to build up your query step by step. Select the whole table first by using `SELECT *`, then try to join it. Then go on. If you got the right table output with the desired fields, redefine your `SELECT` statement to pick the columns that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. Will read this article again in case I missed smth previous time.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', visitor_name, visitor_email, visitor_phone) as visitor_info-detail,
    session_geoip_country,
    session_geoip_city,
    visitor_chats_count,
    agents_names, 
    chat_id,
    SUBSTRING( visitor_description, 1, 100 ) AS manager_note
FROM 
 client_jivo_chat_finished
INNER JOIN 
 client_jivo_chat_finished_messages 
ON client_jivo_chat_finished_messages.chat_id = client_jivo_chat_finished.chat_id